# Correctly format boolean tag attributes with tinymce editor plugin

Tags: tinymce, microdata

i am building a plugin for tinymce editor which adds some microdata to selected text, and i want to make sure the final markup will be valid. as [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#attr-itemscope) by the draft microdata spec, a new item is indicated by adding the attribute `itemscope` to an element, for example:

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://example.com/vocab/someobject" itemid="someid" >
<meta itemprop="topic" content="something very interesting" />
  ....
  other microdata stuff
</section>
```

i have [extended](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:extended_valid_elements) the configuration parameters of tinymce to recognize these microdata attributes:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    schema: "html5",
    extended_valid_elements:"@[itemscope|itemtype|itemid|itemprop|content],div,span,time[datetime]"
    ...
});
```

and things are generally working. however, when i use the plugin, tiny mce is still "correcting" my markup by adding an empty value to the itemscope attribute, like so: `itemscope=""`. but the itemscope attribute is a **boolean** element, which AFAIU means that it should have *no* value.

so the question is, a) is it still valid markup if the itemscope attribute has a value? and b) if not, (how) can i configure tinymce to leave itemscope as a proper boolean attribute, and not append the `=""` bit?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of a boolean attribute [must either be the empty string, or the name of the attribute itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes). So, `<div itemscope>`, `<div itemscope="">`, and `<div itemscope="itemscope">` are all equivalent.